# Language to create flowcharts

Tags: dsl, flowchart

This seems like something which must have been answered before, but I can't find anything appropriate in the question archives. Basically, I'm looking for a little Domain Specific Language to create flowcharts. I'm terrible at graphic design and making things look nice, and I'd really like a langauge where I could write something in code and it would produce a pretty flowchart. I've come across GraphViz, but it seems more suited to creating things like Finite State Machine diagrams, rather than process flowcharts. It also doesn't have the simple DSL-style front-end that would allow me to easily work it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7):

Have a look at [PlantUml](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/) - in particular their [Activity State](http://plantuml.sourceforge.net/activity2.html) diagrams.

As an example (from their site) produces the image below:

```
@startuml

start

if (graphviz installed?) then (yes)
  :process all\ndiagrams;
else (no)
  :process only
  __sequence__ and __activity__ diagrams;
endif

stop

@enduml
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[MindFusion](http://www.mindfusion.eu/index.html) offers components for diagramming that you can access programmatically.

They offer components for WPF and WinForms:

- [WPFDiagram](http://www.mindfusion.eu/wpfdiagram.html) - WPF
- [FlowChart.NET](http://www.mindfusion.eu/flowchart-net.html) - WinForms

In the past I've used their WPF component on a DSL editor project. Based on Toolbox drag-and-drops in the DSL editor, WPFDiagram was called to create shapes on the Drawing Surface.